# Error when trying to read in multiple tsv tables

Tags: r

I keep getting this error when trying to read in multiple tables in R:

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 31 elements 
Here is my code:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.tsv")
data = lapply(temp, read.table)
```

Example tables of the data:

```
Code Number Description
1    10     Heart Failure with Congestion
```

Becomes

```
Code Number Description V1        V2      V3
1    10     Heart       Failure   with    Congestion
```

Comment: Try `lst <- lapply(temp, read.table, fill=TRUE)`

Comment: thanks!  i believe that was a step in the right direction.  I get this error now though: 
 duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: Am i possibly going about it wrong?  I want to read in multiple tables into separate data frames, one for each table.

Comment: Can you try with `row.names=NULL` ?  The `lapply` will read the datasets in to a list, and I think it is better to read it in a list and do all the operations rather than having separate dataframe objects in the global environment

Comment: I just tried adding that.  It runs but it does not create the separate data frames for the 12 tsv files in my folder.

Comment: It creates data in a list, that is what I said.  Did you get a list of dataframes?

Comment: I also tried a for loop with the same error as the original:

`for (i in 1:length(temp)){
  assign(temp[i], 
         read.table(paste(temp[i], sep='', col.names = NULL))
  )}`

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it is better to keep it in a list. But if you insist, `names(lst) <-  sub('\\.tsv', '', temp); list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: yeah, it just says large list.  the data frames dont appear to have separate names

Comment: Im trying to do it as a list.  That is how i applied the lapply before to a different function.

Comment: In the above comment, I changed the names the list with a substring of the `temp`, and used `list2env`.  so, if you type the first `temp` without the `.tsv` part, it will be have the first data.frame

Comment: thanks a lot! its almost there.  For some reason when i run the code on it, the variables with values such as "Heart failure with congestion" are separated into 4 variables, Heart, failure, with, and congrestion.

Comment: i believe it is the spaces separating these words thats causing the problems

Comment: Yes, it must be that, without an example dataset, it is hard to test how to rectify that

Comment: I attached a small sample that i made up that appears to be just what is happening to the original post.  Thank you once again fro your help!

Comment: Have you tried with `\t` as delimiter.  Sometimes, the tab delimiter works, otherwise, we may need to read it with `readLines` and then create a unique delimiter like quotes to separate the column from the rest.  It will depend upon using some regex as well.